# read up a table and analyze the elements matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to realize my idea in matlab. 
I consider two column A and B.

```
A=data(:,1)
B=data(:,5)
```

the data look like:

```
A       B 

1       1
2       1
3       1
...    ...
100     20
...     ...
150     30
151     1 
...    ...
```

The values in column A are timepoints. 
I start with the first element in column A. It schould be `A(1,1)` and look on the first element in the column B `B(1,1)`. If `B(1,1)==1`its true,if not its false. Then I increase consider the second raw of the column A and second raw of the column B and so on until the last raw of A and B.

How can I construck this loop??

Comment: How does the final result looks like?

Comment: the last value of B is 1000. I try to create this function and use it function for a simulink model. The output of a model schould be false or true ( 1 or 0).

Comment: How do you need A in this case?

Comment: A is the input for the model this is a time point, the 1 or 0 schould be the output.

Comment: This is confusing. I don't see how you need A to produce True or False.

Comment: Maybe I am thinking in a wrong way. The input schould be a time ( timepoint), and the output schould be a state (1,0). I dont have any formula. 
So as input I give a data from A (timepoins), in function block, that I write a loop, which is looking what is the state at every point

Answer (score 0):

You can just consider `B` likes the following:

```
result = (B == 1);
```

The `result` would be the same size of `B` such as you want. Nowm you can get the value of `A` on result likes the following:

```
valid_times = A(result);
```

Comment: sorry don't understand what does this line mean?
If there are 1000 lines in the column B so I need to set 1000 for reslult and this command search for all values, which are equal 1??

Comment: why don't you try what @OmG suggested and have a look at the output. `result` is the size of B.

Comment: `result` gives me a column with 1 and 0 as output.

Comment: The values of A are the inputs  for the part of a  model. This is  a time point, the 1 (ready) or 0 (not ready) schould be the output.
For example   input->|query|-> output. I am working on a model for certain devices. The controller gets a feedback from device 1 or 0 and can decide if the device is ready or not. The idea is to do a query: what is at the time point 1, what is at time point 2, what is at time point 3 and so on....